# NSUUID with UUIDString initializer

Tags: swift, xcode6, ibeacon

I am attempting to make a NSUUID with a specified value:

```
let uuidString        = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
let beaconUUID:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)
```

The second line gives an error message:

> Extra Argument 'UUIDString' in call

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUUID/initWithUUIDString:) it seems that it should work. Any ideas?

I hace also added `as String` after `uuidString`, same issue.

Comment: I like your Duke icon there @TofuBeer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message is misleading. `init?(UUIDString string: String)` is a
failable initializer" and returns an optional which has to be unwrapped. So

```
let beaconUUID:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)!
```

or simply

```
let beaconUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)!
```

works. If there is any chance that the initialization fails then use optional binding:

```
if let beaconUUID =  NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString) {
    // ...
} else {
    // failed
}
```

For more information, see

- ["Failable Initializers"](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17)
  in the Swift blog,
- ["Declarations"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) in "The Swift Programming Language".

Comment: Thanks, I had done that before and it did give me nil. Turns out I had dropped off the leading character in the UUID I was passing. A whole new set of error messages to figure out :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)
```

return an optional so you have to declare your variable as optional as well.

```
let uuidString        = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
let beaconUUID:NSUUID? = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is the "!" in swift? I know it is represent NOT meaning, but how come in this case it uses like this? Anyone can explain it to me, I'm new to Swift programming language.

Comment: Swift uses `!` in several distinct ways. The one used in these answers is to force unwrap an Optional value. An Optional type is a regular type, e.g. `String`, which can also be `nil` and is written `String?`.


If you have a value of type `String?` and you want to unwrap it to get a value of type `String` then you use `!` on the value.


In other words, if `x: String?` you can write `x!` to get the plain `String` value wrapped up by the optional. This only works if you know the value is not `nil`, otherwise you will get a runtime exception.

The `!` is to signify the potential danger.